# What does “This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added” mean?

Tags: support, chat, frozen-rooms

I found a chat room on Stack Overflow which would be helpful for me. However, I saw a message at the bottom of that chat room which said:

> This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.

What does this mean? When can I chat there?

Comment: Also the [tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/frozen-rooms/info) for the ([tag:frozen-rooms]) tag contains some basic info on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Chat room is frozen?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/659/chat-room-is-frozen) by Jeff Atwood♦:

> See the /faq for the rules, specifically

> https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention

> > Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

> > Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. **Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen.** Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

> Relevant bit bolded.