# Can this note be changed: "This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added."?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, frozen-rooms

When a chatroom is frozen, only moderators can chat in the chatroom.

> While the room is frozen, only moderators can talk. A room freeze prevents room owners from participating, and prevents the room from appearing in the default list of rooms for the site. Moderators can use this time to leave guidance for the room with reason why it was frozen, to give everyone a chance to calm down, or to permanently close a room while still allowing public access to the transcripts.
>
> [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270)

Example: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58769663#58769663

Other users in the chatrooms will be seeing a note like this:

> This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.

Instead of the above quoted note, I think this kind of note to other users in chatroom would be better: "***This room has been frozen and only chat moderators will be able to chat here.***"

What's your opinion, people?

---

- My question is not a duplicate of [What does “This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added” mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230383) because the post explains the meaning of "This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added." which has nothing to do with my question. My question is a feature request-cum-discussion post about changing "This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added." to something more precise.
- My question is not a duplicate of [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271267) as the post explains the tools which are available to moderators, room owners and normal users to moderate chat. The post does have information about freezing a chatroom but that doesn't make my post a duplicate of it. My post is about changing "This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added." to something more precise, not about knowing what are the tools available to moderate chat.

Comment: Let's not clutter the UI with useless messages. Who will benefit from that updated message? A mod? They know they have super powers. A regular user? They find out soon enough that the freezing message excludes moderators. SE staff can also chat in  frozen room, technically they are not just moderators.

Comment: Additional info: [How are private rooms frozen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304200/how-are-private-rooms-frozen)

Comment: @rene "useless" - depends on the perspective of a person.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that

> This room has been frozen and only chat moderators will be able to chat here.

is solving any problems the current message has.

Minor nitpick: I don't know what chat moderators are. The term is alien to me.

A frozen room is not meant to receive new messages. No two moderators should jump into a frozen room and have chat there. So while they might be *able* to chat, doing so is not the intent of a frozen room. They should stick to the current guidance, which is clear about the use of the option to Freeze a room.

The current message has all the info regular chat users and room owners need. It is relatively short and explains what the frozen state means for those type of users. That specific message does not need to elaborate under which system conditions new messages might appear.

If it is needed to change the wording you need to bring arguments to the table why the current wording is troublesome, for which users it is unclear, how ambiguity of wording confuses users  and what (negative) impact the current wording has. And if you then propose a new phrasing it has of course to address all prior arguments.

The question fails to demonstrate what the issue is and for which group of users. The current wording doesn't have to change now, either because the alternative isn't any better and/or there is not enough evidence the current wording is a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no real point in such a change of wording.

Main reason is, moderators should not be chatting in a frozen room. If they happen to post a message, it's either by mistake, or to explain why they froze the room. If you see a frozen room where moderators chat among themselves on regular basis please report it, it's not proper usage of chat and should be stopped.

Another reason why it's not really needed is because it's common sense that moderators can post in frozen chat rooms. They can post answers to deleted questions, can post comments to deleted posts, etc - so why not such powers in chat?

Comment: What about a simpler message wording, such as "This room is frozen; you cannot add new messages". This retains the simplicity, but doesn't contradict functionality (since it only talks about *you* and doesn't talk about other users).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog then the message should be aware of one's mod/RO status and display a different message to that set of users to be accurate. I don't think that much development is warranted to an ancient system dieing for a rebuild.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't think room owners can chat when the room is frozen.

Comment: @Random is correct